# How can i create retrospective trend over time using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have some troubles creating a retrospective trend over time for next table using just SQL

`user_id       |  Date of Exam   |    Exam Name | Result
-------------- +-----------------+--------------+-------
             1 | 2013-01-01 6:00 | Geography    |     PASS
             1 | 2013-01-02 6:00 | Math         |     FAIL
             1 | 2013-01-03 6:00 | Geography    |     FAIL
             1 | 2013-01-04 6:00 | Biology      |     FAIL
             1 | 2013-01-04 7:00 | Biology      |     PASS
             1 | 2013-01-04 6:00 | Math         |     FAIL
             1 | 2013-01-04 7:00 | Math         |     PASS
             2 | 2013-01-04 7:00 | Math         |     FAIL`

I need to get pass rate for each day during a specific date range. For example for a specific day X  i need to get latest available results as on current day for particular student(if no result is available for current date for him I need to take the one from previous date if previous day result is empty I need to take from the day before and so on). IF multiple results are available for one day for specific student the latest result should be used in calculations, the older one is ignored. I need to get pass percentage for each exam group for a particular day. The resulting table should look like this

`Exam Name |  2013-01-01   |   2013-01-02  |  2013-01-03  | 2013-01-04 
---------- +---------------+-- ------------+--------------+------------
Geography  | 100%          |   100%        |  0%          | 0%
Math       | NULL          |   0%          |  0%          | 50%
Biology    | NULL          |   NULL        |  NULL        | 100%`

As of now i only managed to return multiple tables for each day. But i think it possible to merge it a single table. This is a query to get latest result for a specific day

```
select ExamName, COUNT(*) as TotalCount,
    sum(case when Result = 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end) PassCount 
    from (SELECT  
         UserID, 
         ExamName,            
         Result,
         DateOfExam,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY UserID,  ExamName Order By DateOfExam DESC) AS RowNum
         From  dbo.ExamResults       
    where DateOfExam <= '2013-01-04 7:00'    
       ) T1
where T1.RowNum = 1
group by ExamName
```

SQLFiddle with some DDL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6fde8/2/0

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: With either DBMS you will need to use a pivot or cross tab to make this work the way you want it.

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server 2012. I have found some queries with use a pivot table but I'm not sure how to fit it in my case since for each column i need to perform specific calculations

Comment: How about some ddl and sample data? sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: I have created  all data on SQlFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6fde8/2/0 and added a query how to return total and pass rate for a specific day